# What does the C value mean in the response from SignalR?

Tags: .net, websocket, signalr

I'm using SignalR and wondering what C means?

[image]

`H`, `M` and `A` are explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr#how-hubs-work), but what is `C`, is it a **C**onnection identifier?

What does `d-ED549913-Dv,0|D3,1|D4,2|Dy,24` signify? Is it an identifier? Why is the last number incremented?

What does `S` mean?
[image]

Comment: If it is not documented, then dive into the source code :)

Comment: Looks like some of it is documented here:
https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/main/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Hubs/HubResponse.cs